# Is there a way to create an associative array from a text file in bash?

Tags: bash, git-bash

I'm currently creating a list of commands so for example by saying "directory install plugin-name" I can install all needed plugins specified in an external list. This list is just a txt file with all plugin names. But I'm struggling getting all names in an associative array.

I've tried this one:

```
while IFS=";" read line;
do " communtyList[ $line ]=1 " ;
done < community-list.txt;
```

The desired output should be

- `communityList[test1]=1`
- `communityList[test2]=1`....

It need to be an associative array because I want to access it by words and not by index. This word will be implemented as parameters/arguments.

For example "install plugin" instead of "1 plugin"

So I can ask for example this way:

```
if [ ! -z "${!communtyList[$2]}" ];
```

Update, here the whole code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
community(){
declare -A communtyList
while IFS= read line;
do communtyList[$line]=1 ;
done < community-list.txt;
#     communtyList[test1]=1
#     communtyList[test2]=1
#     communtyList[test3]=1
#     communtyList[test4]=1
if { [ $1 = 'install' ] || [ $1 = 'activate' ] || [ $1 = 'uninstall' ] || [ $1 = 'deactivate' ] ; } && [ ! -z $2 ] ;  then
     if [ $2 = 'all' ];
        then echo "$1 all community plugins....";
        while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$1  $line "; done < community-list.txt;
     elif [ ! -z "${!communtyList[$2]}" ];
        then echo "$1 community plugin '$2'....";
     else
        echo -e "\033[0;31m Something went wrong";
        echo " Plugin '$2' does not exist.";
        echo " Here a list of all available community plugins: ";
        echo ${!communtyList[@]}
        echo -e " \e[m"
    fi
else
    echo -e "\033[0;31m Something went wrong";
    if [ -z $2 ];
        then echo -e "[Plugin name] required. [community][action][plugin name] \e[m"
    else
        echo " Action '$1' does not exist.";
        echo -e " Do you mean some of this? \n install \n activate \n uninstall \e[m"
    fi
fi
echo ${!communtyList[@]}
}
"$@"
```

Comment: `sh` does not have associative arrays at all. See perhaps also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: So is there no workaround?

Comment: Your original question asked if this can be done in `sh` or `bash`; it can be done in Bash, but not in `sh`. They are two different shells.

Comment: Ok Your right, i should have aked "how" sorry for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use asociative array you have to declare it first

```
declare -A communityList
```

Then you can add values

```
communityList[test1]=1
communityList[test2]=2
...
```

Or with the declaration

```
declare -A communityList=(
    communityList[test1]=1
    communityList[test2]=2
    ...
)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your anser. The declaration was already in my script but i did not added it here. maybe i should post the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes around `" communtyList[ $line ]=1 "` mean you try to evaluate a command whose first character is a space. You want to take out those quotes, and probably put quotes around `"$line"` instead.

It's also unclear why you have `IFS=";"` -- you are not splitting the line into fields anyway, so this is not doing anything useful. Are there semicolons in your input file? Where and why; what do they mean?

You should probably prefer `read -r` unless you specifically require `read` to do odd things with backslashes in the input.

Finally, as suggested by Ivan, you have to declare the array's type as associative before you try to use it.

With those things out of the way, try

```sh
declare -A communityList

while read -r line; do
    communtyList["$line"]=1
done < community-list.txt
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry that didn't work for me :) It says ") syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
But thank you for you answer

Comment: Looks like you probably used a Windows editor. That's unrelated to this answer, and a common FAQ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings

Comment: Currently im running git-bash and the code is written in a sh file. Maybe i'm confusing here something i learned today for the first time bash/sh commands :S

Comment: Bash doesn't care what you call your file; but the `.sh` extension is misleading for human readers.

Comment: so what should it be instaed?

Comment: If it was called `donkeys.sh` a better name would be `donkeys`.